# How to remove all next elements from list of object on condition in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have one list of objects

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

How to remove all next elements from list when there is a match on condition something like-

```
if(object1.Price== 0)
{
  //remove all next elements from list
}
```

I want to keep the list from 0 to matching position like if price is zero at index 5 then take 0 to 5 elements.

Comment: Are you iterating the list? Do you want to keep all elements before this one? ex. element at index 2 matches, so you keep zero and one as well, but drop anything after index 2? Or do you want to get the first element that matches only?

Comment: One option: you can find the index with `FindIndex()` then use `RemoveRange()`.

Comment: Finding the matching element is done with FindIndex.  You haven't made clear whether you want to 1) actually remove elements after that from the original list, or 2) produce a new list consisting of only the elements up to and including the matching one, or 3) just iterate over the elements up to the matching one without actually making a new list or modifying the original one (this may be the fastest option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `List<T>` where `T` is `Card` you can use `List<T>.FindIndex` to get the index of the first element matching the predicate and get the range of the List:

```
List<Card> cards = new List<Card> { new Card {Id = 1, Price = 1.0, Name = "Ace" }, 
new Card {Id = 2, Price = 0.0, Name="Two" }};
Predicate<Card> test1 = a => a.Price == 1.0;
Predicate<Card> test2 = b => b.Price == 0.0;
//You can also do something like this:
Predicate<Card> test3 = c => c.Price == 1.0 && c.Id == 1;


Console.WriteLine(GetCardRange(cards, test1).Count); //Prints 1
Console.WriteLine(GetCardRange(cards, test2).Count); //Prints 2
Console.WriteLine(GetCardRange(cards, test3).Count); //Prints 1

//or shorthand without declaring a Predicate:
Console.WriteLine(GetCardRange(cards, (a) => a.Price == 0.0).Count); //Prints 2


//Method accepts a predicate so you can pass in different
//types of condition(s)
public List<Card> GetCardRange(List<Card> cards, Predicate<Card> p)
{
    int index = cards.FindIndex(p);
    //if no card is found, either return the whole list 
    //or change to return null or empty list
    return index == -1 ? cards : 
       cards.GetRange(0, index + 1);
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: in my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73479622/how-different-are-null-and-emptiness that was just deleted by some hostile users, about NULL vs emptiness, the emptiness  appears in a column with type float, so is not the empty string ""

Comment: @Tim Welcome to Stackoverflow, hostile is everyday here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `TakeWhile` and `Select`, e.g.:

```
var lst = new List<Card>()      {
     new Card() { Price = 2 },
     new Card() { Price = 1 },
     new Card() { Price = 0 },
     new Card() { Price = -1 },
     new Card() { Price = -2 },         
};
var found = false;      
var items = lst.TakeWhile(x => !found).Select(x => 
{
    if (x.Price == 0)
        found = true;
    return x;
});
```

This leads to items with price 2, 1, 0 being kept while -1 and -2 are removed.

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g0UmM2) to test.

Comment: This is better than removing items that you don't want from an existing list.  Just produce a new list with the items you do want.